# Need help with a symbol, seems like inverted $\in$.

Tags: notation

Need help with a symbol that appears in logic notations, as it appears (for the first time, in the book) on page 2 of the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zrVtCKA3CO4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) : Elements of Real Analysis, by Denlinger.

The logical statement  containing the symbol is stated below with its interpretation in the book:

> **Existential Qualifier : $\exists \,\ x \in A$ 'symbol' $P(x)$**
>
> If $P(x)$ is a statement about $x$, and $A$ is a set, then $"\exists x \in A,$ 'symbol' $ P(x)"$ is the statement, "There exists at least one element in the set $A$ such that $P(x)$ is true."

My interpretation is that it is same as: $":"$ or $"|"$, that also mean : "such that"; but worry if am correct or not.

Also, the book never uses the symbols: $":"$ or $"|"$, & is always using instead the given symbol, whenever the meaning needed is : "such that".

If correct, then is there such symbol available in MathJax?

[image]

*Edit :*

As per the comment by @MinusOne-Twelfth, it is listed as second symbol, by Detexify, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's used by some authors to mean "such that".

Comment: Try `\ni` to get $\ni$.

Comment: As far as whether there is a MathJax implementation, I'm not sure, but for universal clarity, I would just use "such that", or possibly "s.t.". Of course, in the context of set-builder notation, the symbols "$\mid"$ or ":" are standard.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks a lot. Is there a webpage or other source listing table of all symbols in MathJax.

Comment: There probably is if you search online. Another useful resource is [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). You can draw the symbol you are looking for and it will give suggestions.